# List being overwritten during a transformation

Tags: python, python-3.x

Well, I'm creating an ORM-like behaviour to a class of mine. Once I fetch the data from a database I want to generate a list of typed instances, so I can add some extra behaviour to them later.

The ModelBase class should be inherited by any new Model, as Book(ModelBase).

Once you call Book.query(), the query method in ModelBase is called. When I debug the rows variable within this method I receive 4 different rows.

But once I iterate over rows list and calls a generate_new_instance by each row, the ending list returns only the last row received.

What am I probably missing here? Instead of `object.__new__(self)`, I've tried also `self()`. Same behaviour.

In my opinion, the bug is in generate_new_instance method, so each row is overwriting the last row.

```
class ModelBase(object):
    ....
    def query(self, filters=None, order=None):
        ....
        rows = list(query.fetch())
        return [self.generate_new_instance(i) for i in rows]

    @classmethod
    def generate_new_instance(self, result):
        obj = object.__new__(self)   # ATTENTION HERE.
        obj.id = result.key.id
        obj.data_bag = result

        for k in result:
            if not hasattr(obj, k):
                continue

            prop = getattr(obj, k)
            setattr(prop, 'value', result[k])

        return obj

class Property(object):
    data_type = None
    value = None

    def __init__(self, data_type):
        self.data_type = data_type


class StringProperty(Property):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('string')


class Book(dsh.ModelBase):
    title = dsh.StringProperty()
    description = dsh.StringProperty()
    author_name = dsh.StringProperty()
```

Someone there has some idea to help me to solve it?

Best regards,

Comment: That should probably `type(self)()`